MCAP - adding metadata
I have encountered an obstacle that I am not able to overcome, maybe you will be able to help me. I am working on creating a new mcap file (using python). Basically what I need to do is: add some messages, create a header with custom stamp values and add metadata.
I tried to achieve this using this library and class: from mcap_ros2.writer import Writer but unfortunately there is no support for the add_metadata() function that exists in this library from mcap.writer import Writer.
The reason why I don't use the mcap.writer class is because I'm not able to pass custom values to the header (stamp), which on the other hand I can achieve with the mcap_ros2.writer class.
Any ideas how I can add metadata using the mcap_ros2.writer class? Or, is it possible to add (append) metadata to an existing mcap file using python (not CLI)? Thank you in advance for whatever you can offer to help!
